# bash: Batch reformatting using sed + date?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

> "2004-03-23 20:11:55" 3 3 1
>
> "2004-03-23 20:12:20" 1 1 1
>
> "2004-03-31 02:20:04" 15 15 1
>
> "2004-04-07 14:33:48" 141 141 1
>
> "2004-04-15 02:08:31" 2 2 1
>
> "2004-04-15 07:56:01" 1 2 1
>
> "2004-04-16 12:41:22" 4 4 1

and I need to feed this data to a program which only accepts time in UNIX (Epoch) format. Is there a way I can change all the dates in bash? My first instinct tells me to do something like this:

```
sed 's/"(.*)"/`date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %T" "\1" "+%s"`'
```

But I am not entirely sure that the `\1` inside the `date` call will properly backreference the regex matched by sed. In fact, when I run this, I get the following response:

> sed: 1: "s/(".*")/`date -jf "% ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on this? Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a `/` at the end of the command, that's why the error you see. Now, not that it's going to work, anyway

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is going to be expanded between [single quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Also, no, the shell expansions are going to happen before the `sed` `\1` expansion, so your code isn't going to work. How about something like this (untested):

```
while IFS= read -r date time a b c
do
    date --date "${date:1} ${time::-1}" # Cut the variables to remove the literal quotes
    printf " %s %s %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
done < file
```